# Pull a single entry from nested list of dicts by key

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
[{'id': 10259,
  'cuisine': 'greek',
  'ingredients': ['romaine lettuce',
   'black olives',
   'grape tomatoes',
   'garlic',
   'pepper',
   'purple onion',
   'seasoning',
   'garbanzo beans',
   'feta cheese crumbles']},
 {'id': 25693,
  'cuisine': 'southern_us',
  'ingredients': ['plain flour',
   'ground pepper',
   'salt',
   'tomatoes',
   'ground black pepper',
   'thyme',
   'eggs',
   'green tomatoes',
   'yellow corn meal',
   'milk',
   'vegetable oil']},
 {'id': 20130,
  'cuisine': 'filipino',
  'ingredients': ['eggs',
   'pepper',
   'salt',
   'mayonaise',
   'cooking oil',
   'green chilies',
   'grilled chicken breasts',
   'garlic powder',
   'yellow onion',
   'soy sauce',
   'butter',
   'chicken livers']}]
```

I'm trying to write a function to pull the `ingredients` list for the dict where id == some number, but I can't quite work it out.

At first I tried

```
def get_ingredients(recipe):
    for recipe in recipes:
        return recipe['ingredients']
```

But that seems to return the ingredients for whatever entry has `index==recipe`

How do I easily access the next level of the dict?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're given the `id` of the dictionary you want to get the `ingredients` of - in which case you will want something like this:

```
def get_ingredients(id):
    for recipe in recipes:
        if recipe['id'] == id:
            return recipe['ingredients']
```

Note that this will return `None` if you pass it an id that doesn't exist for any dictionary in your list.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to access a dictionary inside a list.
assuming that `recipe` is your dataset and its in the global namespace, you can do this:

```
def get_ingradients(id): 

    for recipe in recipes: 
        if recipe.get("id") == id: 
            return recipe.get("ingredients")
```

this will return the list of the ingradients of the id you passed.

Comment: That returns `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'`

Comment: I thought you have dictionary inside of dictionary's. Check the code again please. @LMGagne

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the dataset is a dictionary and the id you want is from the `id` field, you can rebuild the dictionary with the id field as the key.

```
dd = [
{'id': 10259, 'cuisine': 'greek', 'ingredients': ['romaine lettuce', 'black olives', 'grape tomatoes', 'garlic', 'pepper', 'purple onion', 'seasoning', 'garbanzo beans', 'feta cheese crumbles']},
{'id': 25693, 'cuisine': 'southern_us', 'ingredients': ['plain flour', 'ground pepper', 'salt', 'tomatoes', 'ground black pepper', 'thyme', 'eggs', 'green tomatoes', 'yellow corn meal', 'milk', 'vegetable oil']},
{'id': 20130, 'cuisine': 'filipino', 'ingredients': ['eggs', 'pepper', 'salt', 'mayonaise', 'cooking oil', 'green chilies', 'grilled chicken breasts', 'garlic powder', 'yellow onion', 'soy sauce', 'butter', 'chicken livers']}
]

dnew = {x['id']:x['ingredients'] for x in dd}

print(dnew[10259])
```

Output

```
['romaine lettuce', 'black olives', 'grape tomatoes', 'garlic', 'pepper', 'purple onion', 'seasoning', 'garbanzo beans', 'feta cheese crumbles']
```

Comment: It's a list of dicts, not a dict of dicts

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
data_dict = {0: {'id': 10259, 'cuisine': 'greek', 'ingredients': ['romaine lettuce', 'black olives', 'grape tomatoes', 'garlic', 'pepper', 'purple onion', 'seasoning', 'garbanzo beans', 'feta cheese crumbles']},
1: {'id': 25693, 'cuisine': 'southern_us', 'ingredients': ['plain flour', 'ground pepper', 'salt', 'tomatoes', 'ground black pepper', 'thyme', 'eggs', 'green tomatoes', 'yellow corn meal', 'milk', 'vegetable oil']},
2: {'id': 20130, 'cuisine': 'filipino', 'ingredients': ['eggs', 'pepper', 'salt', 'mayonaise', 'cooking oil', 'green chilies', 'grilled chicken breasts', 'garlic powder', 'yellow onion', 'soy sauce', 'butter', 'chicken livers']}}

recipe_id = 25693
[x for x in data_dict.values() if x['id']==recipe_id][0]['ingredients']
```

Output

````
['plain flour',
 'ground pepper',
 'salt',
 'tomatoes',
 'ground black pepper',
 'thyme',
 'eggs',
 'green tomatoes',
 'yellow corn meal',
 'milk',
 'vegetable oil']```
````